# devcomponents ribbon bar quick access toolbar

Tags: c#, dotnetbar

I trying to use the Quick access toolbar on Dev Components Ribbon Bar, it works fine if I set it in the designer.
But if I change the 'CanCustomize' flag on a 'BaseItem' on the form load event the customize dialog does NOT pick this up.
I wondered if there is a command I can call to tell the ribbon bar to redefine itself?
or if I have to redefine the ribbon bar entirely?

I have tried calling RecalcLayout as beloww

```
BaseItem.CanCustomize = false
RibbonBar.RecalcLayout()
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Did you try to ask this to Devcomponents support?

Comment: thanks for adding dotnetbar tag, I was asking anyone really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi have figured out what works for this.

```
BaseItem.visible = false
```

this will stop it from being shown on the QAT, but it will still be visible on the customize menu, i still want to stop some of these being shown, but have NOT figured that out yet.